# How to specify dataType: 'json' in Angular.js $http.post?

Tags: ajax, json, angularjs

I would like to specify `dataType: 'json'` as in conventional jQuery `$.ajax`.
Is this possible with Angular.js `$http.post` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

> Transforming Requests and Responses
>   Both requests and responses can be transformed using transform functions. By default, Angular applies these transformations:
>
> Request transformations:
>
> - if the data property of the request config object contains an object, serialize it into JSON format.
>     Response transformations:
> - if XSRF prefix is detected, strip it (see Security Considerations section below)
> - **if json response is detected, deserialize it using a JSON parser**

So no need to set a data type it is done automatically

Comment: The problem is that the server responds with HTML/XML/JSON depending on dataType. The URL is always the same.

Comment: @Paul are you talking about the `Accept` header.

Comment: I am talking about `Content-type` in request

Comment: @Paul so the server reads the request content type to determine the response type?

Comment: @Paul FYI jQuery sets the `Accept` header when you set dataType to 'json' not the `Content-Type` header

Answer (score 20):

You can use the HTTP Config object to set the headers:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'somewhere.xyz',
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
})
```

Comment: good, i only extend comment before. You'll need to setup headers always if you are sending json objects as response from server side. Normal classic print({id: 11}) may throw you error. Setup header content-type as json and should works fine. Cya

Comment: ARGGGGH dude, u just saved my day! I've been pulling my hair out wondering why the hell my Node/Express4 wouldn't parse POST data... turns out I had to forse the header content type in my angular $http requests..... god dammit!

Comment: There is no need to set the above because it is the default. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers. The fact that this helped you, probably indicates that your code was setting the default header someplace else to another value.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem,  `responseType:'json'` solved the issue

You can use responseType:'json' instead of dataType:'json'

```
var promise = $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'somewhere.xyz',
            responseType:'json'

        });
```

For further reference 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#methods_jsonp

Comment: In https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage reponseType directs you to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#xmlhttprequest-responsetype which makes it sound like an override of the server Content-Type with the caution: "When setting responseType to a particular value, the author should make sure that the server is actually sending a response compatible to that format. If the server returns data that is not compatible to the responseType that was set, the value of response will be null."