# How to add dataType property of ajax in $http of angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, http

I want to make  a rest call to server using Angular but I am block I tried with traditional jQuery ajax call with Basic Authorization header looks something like this:

```
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/public/emp",
            type: "GET",
            dataType:"jsonp",
            Accept : "application/json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXXX'
            },
            success: function (data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
```

It works perfectly and Data is retrieved.

But When I try to convert it with $http of AngularJs. Something like this:

```
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost:8080/public/emp',
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXX',"content-type":"application/json","Accept" : "application/json"}})
        .success(function (data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            alert("error");
        });
```

Its giving me Error 401 - Unauthorized

How can I add dataType property to $http? I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205037/how-to-specify-datatype-json-in-angular-js-http-post) link of stack overflow but Still unable to get a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [$http.jsonp](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp) method? 
For your case this should work like this:

```
$http.jsonp('http://localhost:8080/public/emp', {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXX',
            "content-type":"application/json",
            "Accept" : "application/json"
        }});
```

Also here is working plunker [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UrHK6c9iJYGHeU6SWrHQ). And more general one [from angular team](http://plnkr.co/edit/tqeko8NjFqJWiVhM5IVn?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, The call completed but Its callbacked in error response. Moreover this being a REST call how can I mention it is a GET request so that server responds correctly ?

Comment: I got it working and data is also retrieved by adding third parameter `data-type` somethin like this: `[{'data-type':"json"}]` but I am getting the callback in error function.

Comment: @user3256761 this is already GET request. [Here is example](http://plnkr.co/edit/UrHK6c9iJYGHeU6SWrHQ?p=preview) for both Angular and jQuery jsonp requests. You can see that the only difference they have is the callback function. If you can craft a sample this could help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this get method

In js

```
$http({
                url: 'customUrl',
                method: 'GET',
                params: {},
            }).then(function (result) {
                return result;
            }).catch(function (e) {
                throw e;
            });
```

In api

```
[HttpGet]
    public string GetDraftData(byte id)
    {
        return string;
    }
```

Try this post method

In js

```
                $http({
                    url: 'customUrl',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: yourJsonData,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' },
                    //params: { jsonData: "I am shohel rana" },
                    //timeout: 10,
                    //cache: false,
                    //transformRequest: false,
                    //transformResponse: false
                }).then(function (success) {
                    return success;
                }).catch(function (e) {
                    throw e;
                });
```

In api

```
       [HttpPost]
        public bool SaveDraft([FromBody]object draft)
        {
            try
            {
                return _iDraftDataSvc.InsertDraftData(draft);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the method from GET to JSONP. I'm not quite sure if it's possible to add custom headers though (as I've heard), I haven't tried that yet.

```
$http({
    method:'JSONP',
    url : 'http://localhost:8080/public/emp',
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXXXXXXX',"content-type":"application/json","Accept" : "application/json"}})
.success(function (data) {
    alert("success");
})
.error(function (error) {
    alert("error");
});
```