# 400 error when converting from ajax to $http?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs

I am trying to complete a GET request using $http instead of ajax. The call works perfectly with ajax, but when I try to do the same thing with $http I get a 400 (Bad Request) error. I believe I am following the Angular documentation correctly. Any ideas? Hopefully this will also be helpful for others experiencing the same issue.

The ajax code that works:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    accept: 'application/json',
    url: myURL,
    headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + basicKey},
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: requestPayload,
    async: false
}).done(function(serverData) {
    console.log(serverData.access_token);
}).fail(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

The $http code that does not work:

```
var basicConfig = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: myURL,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + basicKey, 
        'Accept': "application/json", 
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
    },
    data: requestPayload 
}

$http(basicConfig).success(function(data, status){
    console.log(status);
}).error(function(data, status){
    console.log(status);
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not setting the dataType in your `$http` request?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I was under the impression you don't need the data type when using $http (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205037/how-to-specify-datatype-json-in-angular-js-http-post)

Comment: use `params` instead of `data`. `data` is the request body, used for POST requests, whereas `params` are query string variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `params` instead of `data`. `data` is the request body, used for POST requests, whereas `params` is for query string variables in GET requests.