# Laravel AngularJS $http request alway empty

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I know there's already a lot of answers to this question but none of them seems to match to my problem so here it is.

I'm using AngularJS's $http to make a GET request to my Laravel 5.6 controller.

The controller ClientsController looks like :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Client;

class ClientsController extends Controller
{
    public function activate($id) {
        $client = Client::find($id);
        return $client;
    }

}
```

where App\Client refers to an existing model.

On route, it looks like :

```
Route::get('/clients/activate/{id}', 'Admin\\ClientsController@activate');
```

and the request form angularJS :

```
$http({
    url: client_url_with_id
    method: "GET"
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

It always shows empty. I don't understand why.

Comment: try return response()->json($client) instead of return. Are you sure you are getting 200 response

Comment: response.status is always 200 but response.data always empty

Comment: Is the correct `$id` being passed? does the `$client` var actually contain anything? Have you tried returning a string to see if this is in the response?

Comment: what is the result of `response` instead of `response.data`?

Comment: Try setting the dataType specifically to json if you are expecting json. This helped my similar issue yesterday. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205037/how-to-specify-datatype-json-in-angular-js-http-post